# How do I format strings output in Chapel?

Tags: string-formatting, chapel

When I'm printing numbers with Chapel's [Formatted I/O](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html?highlight=format#FormattedIO.string.format) I can set the length of numbers with something like

```
writeln("my number is %{#.###}", 3.14159)
```

I want to something similar with strings, but I don't see an example on the page.  Basically, I'd like the string to line up in nice columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is confusing `writeln` with `writef`. To use formatted IO in `writeln`, you'll need to invoke the `.format()` method. Here is an example that demonstrates the string format specifier (`%s`) and the generic format specifier (`%t`). These are listed on the page you've linked in the question.

```
config var someString = 'ben';

// String format specifier
writeln('%s is great'.format(someString));
writef('%s is awesome\n', someString);


// Generic format specifier invokes the readThis / writeThis of the object
writeln('%t is awesome x%t'.format(someString, 2));
```

Output:

```
ben is great
ben is awesome
"ben" is awesome x2
```

Note that string objects include quotes in their `writeThis` method, so you get quotes when using a string with the generic format specifier.

Comment: I suppose that begs the question: Who is this awesome guy?  Also, I tried using `writeln(" %8s is even awesomer!".format("Brad"))`  So how does the `%8s` play into this?

Comment: To quote the documentation: "when writing - a string left padded (right justified) to 8 columns"

Comment: Using the string `"Brad"` may result in a compiler error for that particular string, however.